# MySQL - Select biggest date for each group of dates

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

SELECT * FROM checkin;

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | userid |    date_checked     |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 1  |   15   | 2019-10-08 10:22:15 | 
| 2  |   15   | 2019-10-08 10:22:42 | 
| 3  |   15   | 2019-10-08 10:23:01 | 
| 4  |   40   | 2019-10-08 10:23:44 | 
| 5  |   15   | 2019-10-08 10:24:06 | 
| 6  |   15   | 2019-10-08 10:24:09 | 
| 7  |    3   | 2019-10-08 10:24:59 | 
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

I want to select the rows with the highests date_checked for each group of consecutive equal userid's.
In this example, I would expect something like this:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | userid |    date_checked     |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 3  |   15   | 2019-10-08 10:23:01 | 
| 4  |   40   | 2019-10-08 10:23:44 | 
| 6  |   15   | 2019-10-08 10:24:09 | 
| 7  |    3   | 2019-10-08 10:24:59 | 
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

Please, before tagged as "duplicated of", note that: I don't like DISTINTC of userid column, the same userid can be repeated several times.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical gaps and island problem. Assuming that you are using MySQL 8.0, you can solve it using ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT
    MAX(id) id,
    userid,
    MAX(date_checked) date_checked
FROM (
     SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_checked) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_checked) rn2
    FROM checkin t
) x
GROUP BY rn1 - rn2, userid
```

Comment: TIL the term `gaps and islands` +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  `SELECT id, userid, MAX(date_checked) max_date_checked FROM checkin GROUP BY userid;`

Comment: This is OK for DISTINCT userid's, but isn't my case, the userid can be repeated several times... thanks!!